# Code is getting into errorhandler even when the task is done without errors

Tags: excel

I use a workbook that copy information from others workbooks, using the following Code:

```
Sub importarbens()
On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
```

{...}

```
ErrorHandler:
    Workbooks(nomearq2).Close
    MsgBox "Arquivo Incompatível"
    Exit Sub


End Sub
```

But apparently my code always get in the ErrorHandler, even when the code runs withouth erros and after the task is done. The message in message box appears
When I disable the errorhandler the code works well

Comment: Well what is preventing your code from proceeding into the error handling ?  Do you not have `Exit Sub` right above `ErrorHandler:`?  `ErrorHandler:` is just a line label - it does not have any particular significance such that your code sees it and does not continue, so you have to explicitly tell your code to exit before it gets there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add Exit Sub:

```
Sub importarbens()
On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
{...}

Exit Sub  '<< end of the "happy path" for your code....

ErrorHandler:
    Workbooks(nomearq2).Close
    MsgBox "Arquivo Incompatível"

    Exit Sub '<< Don't really need this since you're already 
             '   at the end of the sub


End Sub
```